# How could I re-write this java method with a while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

It's supposed to take the last element out of a pseudo-LinkedList. The instructions suggested using a while loop to find the next-to-last element.

```
public String removeFromEnd() {
    String removed = null;
    if (head == null) {
        return removed;
    } else if (head.getNext() == null) {
        removed = head.getName();
        head = null;
    } else if (head.getNext().getNext() == null) {
        removed = head.getNext().getName();
        head.setNext(null);
    }
    return removed;
}
```

Past attempts usually look similar to this:

```
public String removeFromEnd() {
    String removed = null;
    while (head.getNext().getNext() == null){
        removed = head.getNext().getName();
        head.setNext(null);
    }
    if (head.getNext() == null){
        removed = head.getName();
                    head = null;
    }
    return removed;
}
```

Comment: A million different things. I seem to always get null pointer exceptions or the wrong values returned. My methods usually have a while loop like this: while (head.getNext().getNext() == null) {...} but then it seems like I'm always leaving out at least one case.

Comment: Put your attempted solutions in the question, not in the comments, please.  Nobody can read multiple lines of code as a comment.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Chuck Norris can read multiple lines of code as a comment.

Comment: Get a reference to the first element, check if the next is null, and if not set your reference to the next element and this in a while loop... Do not use getNext().getNext() constructs, as you have not even checked if getNext() is null

Answer (score 2):

```
  Node node = head;
  Node prev = null;
  while (node != null && node.getNext() != null) {
      prev = node;
      node = node.getNext();
  }
```

Comment: Tried plugging it in, returns null when it should have returned a name. So I'm not sure if it's incomplete or what.

Comment: Yes, this is just the loop to iterate to the end of the list, now think what is missing, you basically have done the missing work in your own example already...

Answer (score 1):

```
// Java Code
public String removeFromEnd() {
String removed = null;
Node prev = null;
Node node = head;
        while(node != null && node.getNext() != null)
        {
            prev = node;
            node = node.getNext();
        }
        //the while loop should move the node to the end of the list
        if(node != null)
        {
        removed = node.getName();
        node = prev;
        node.getNext().removeNode();
        node.setNext(null);
        }
        return removed;
}
```

Comment: To make it more readable you might consider removing the else, as the code will return if head == null

Comment: Thanks Tim. That should be the best way to approach this problem. If my math is right, this should take O(n) time to complete and everything else is pretty much constant work.

Comment: Oh, what is the call to removeNode?  that method doesn't exist (and it works without it).

Comment: This gives me a null pointer exception when I try to setNext(null)

Comment: Why yes, we do not know what data structure your node is, but that is a good guess on how to actually remove the last element from the list. If you provide the information on how to actually remove the item from the list, we could provide a working sample. But you should be able to do so on your own by now.

Answer (score 1):

In your attempt code...

```
while (head.getNext().getNext() == null){
    removed = head.getNext().getName();
    head.setNext(null);
}
```

You'll only enter this loop when `head` is already the second-to-last element.  You want to loop *until* `head` is the second-to-last element.  Does that help at all?

Comment: Somewhat. I guess I keep trying to use the while loop as a conditional instead of an actual loop. Thanks.